# Calling another program from Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a script that calls another program (EES - Engineering Equation Solver) and performs some calculations there and returns the results. The problem I am encountering is that everytime I call the EES from Matlab, it starts the EES but does not solve the EES equations. Instead, I have to then manually press the "solve" button inside the EES, close the EES and after that the results are returned to Matlab.

Is it possible to use a command inside Matlab to solve the EES equations automatically?

The current solution I have is the following, but it only starts the EES and does not solve it automatically:

```
system ('c:\ees32\ees.exe c:\EES32\testing\solverfile.ees /solve'); %call EES and solve
```

Thanks!

On a second thought, this is something that is dependent on the EES program and the commands that are possible to use there. So this is probably not the best place for asking this questions.

Comment: If you run the same command via dos shell, does it work properly?

Comment: Do you mean the command prompt? I don't have much experience with it, what should I write there? Exactly the same command?

Comment: Yes, the same command. If it does not work there as well, there is something wrong with this command line or ees, which is unrelated to matlab.

Comment: Seems like the problem is with the EES. The /solve parameter can only be used with a professional version of EES. 
But thanks for the help!